# What is the name of this convex figure?

Tags: terminology, elementary-functions

The figure is given by $x^4+y^4\leq\frac1{2^4}$ https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E4+%2B+y%5E4+%3C1%2F16.

In general is there a name for the figure $x^{2t}+y^{2t}\leq\frac1{2^{2t}}$ or anything resembling it (at $t\rightarrow\infty$ it becomes a square)?

Comment: Well, the boundary is a [superellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superellipse)

Comment: @Fakemistake It seems to be a hyperellipse.

Comment: I've found in the same wikipedia article the name "ball in the $n$-norm"

Answer (score 1):

The $\ell^p$ ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$ of radius $r$ centered at the origin is
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d : \sum_{i=1}^d |x_i|^p \le r^p\}.$$

Your example is $d = 2$, $p = 2t$, and $r=1/2$.